# Can't enter password because Sticky Keys is enabled

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard

I have a Windows 8.1 PC and accidentally spilled water over my keyboard. I took some keys out, tried to let it dry and get the water out. While doing this a lot of keys get mashed.

I restarted my PC and now I cannot login because I think I got the "Sticky Keys" functionality enabled and cannot type any characters now. I thought that it was the keyboard but using the on screen keyboard for the login yields that I still cannot type any normal characters.

Does anyone know how to bypass this and disable Sticky Keys in the Login Screen?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. For some reason highlighting two symbols (such as ∂∆) and then pressing ALT + X resulted in the symbols being replaced by numbers (such as 40). Because a Windows password requires you to have letters or numbers additionally to symbols I could now change my Windows password to something like 40@@@@@@ and login. I then went to control panel and disabled Sticky Keys.

Comment: You should mark this as the answer since you solved your own problem :)

Answer (score 1):

For next time, you can also toggle sticky keys by tapping the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key 5 times